# javascript that hides/shows element based on criteria not working with style.display = "none"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this section of javascript in my html that grabs a form input, puts it through a function and returns a json. I then want to either hide or show certain form elements based on the values in this json.

At the moment, i can do all of this fine except for changing the style.display properties of the elements im trying to hide/show, i can find them okay with getElementbyId (have tested this with other stuff) but the changes i make to the style don't seem to do anything.

As you can see below, i have put in a few alerts to make sure everything is working, and they all seem to align with what i need from the function. The alert showing style.display even matches up with what i'm trying to change it to, however even if it says "none", the form element still shows up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let selected = document.getElementById('selection1');
    let optional_toggle = document.getElementById("optional_element");
    let button = document.getElementById("button")

     button.onclick = function() {
        choice1 = selected.value;

        fetch('/form_choice/' + choice1).then(function(response) {

            response.json().then(function(data) {

                if (data.show_optional === "True") {
                    optional_toggle.style.display = ""
                    window.alert("first part of if");
                    window.alert(optional_toggle.style.display);
                    window.alert(data.show_optional);
                }
                else {
                    optional_toggle.style.display = "none"
                    window.alert("second part of if");
                    window.alert(optional_toggle.style.display);
                    window.alert(data.show_optional);
                    console.log(optional_toggle);
                }
                }
            )
            }
        )
    }
</script>
```

Edit: i added the console.log lines in but nothing seems to show in the console.
[console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wKGh.png)

Comment: I think the condition `data.show_optional === "True"` always true , or your optional_toggle  isn't loaded , try console log your element

Comment: @Spring I've tried switching bits around and i don't think it's the case that the first part is always True, as the alerts do show a switch between the first and second part of the if. Could you please explain a bit more about what you mean re: the optional_toggle not being loaded/console logging it, as i'm new to this and not sure what you mean! Thank you

Comment: meant the code is executed before dom loaded ,  could you show waht the code show ins console  `console.log(optional_toggle)`

Comment: Oh okay, i'm just trying to figure out how to show the console log with the IDE im using, as i can't seem to see the log in browser or python console

Comment: you can see log in browser , just type 'F12' and click on console TAB

Comment: I tried that, but the console.log(optional_toggle) line i put in below the alerts from my original code doesn't seem to show anything. I've added a screenshot and the console.log lines in my original post above

Comment: @Spring okay, i managed to get it show in the log, and now it shows "input#optional_element" followed by "navigated to wrapdata", with wrapdata being the page name

Comment: that's weird , may be you have a style applied to input with `!important` could you share your html css

Comment: i think i've figured it out now, thank you for your help! it was a struggle trying to find where to look for answers but you pointed me in the write direction :)

Comment: Glad to hear that ; great :) ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the page was reloading to it's original state after the script had been executed, so i stopped this by adding "; return false" after the function like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let selected = document.getElementById('selection1');
    let optional_toggle = document.getElementById("optional_element");
    let button = document.getElementById("button")

     button.onclick = function() {
        choice1 = selected.value;

        fetch('/form_choice/' + choice1).then(function(response) {

            response.json().then(function(data) {

                if (data.show_optional === "True") {
                    optional_toggle.style.display = ""
                    window.alert("first part of if");
                    window.alert(optional_toggle.style.display);
                    window.alert(data.show_optional);
                }
                else {
                    optional_toggle.style.display = "none"
                    window.alert("second part of if");
                    window.alert(optional_toggle.style.display);
                    window.alert(data.show_optional);
                    console.log(optional_toggle);
                }
                }
            )
            }
        ); return false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you can also prevent default action on button using this code , without return `button.onclick = function(e) { e.preventDefault();  ..... }`